# Async call not working in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, long-polling

The following code is my frontend code for a http long poll. In this I am expecting the code setTimeout(getChat, 0) to call the method asynchronously. But when the getChat method's XHR is pending all following XHRs of different methods are also getting into pending state.

```
discussTask = function(taskId) {
  taskIdChat = taskId
  getChat() // initial call
}
var getChat = function() {
  taskId = taskIdChat
  payLoad = {
    'task_id': taskIdChat,
    'recent_message_id': recentMessageId
  }
  var xmlhttp = XHR('/chat/sync', 'POST', payLoad)
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
      buildChat(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText))
      setTimeout(getChat, 0) // Async recursive call
    }
  }
}
var XHR = function(action, method, payLoad) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xmlhttp.open(method, action, true)
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
  xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(payLoad))
  return xmlhttp
}
```

Comment: What are "different methods"? Why do you make request with same parameters?

Comment: Please put `;` at the end of your statements. Depending on ASI is dangerous.

Comment: what's the matter about setting TaskIdChat and afterwards setting TaskId again to the same value as you set TaskIdChat before?

Comment: @Unlockedluca The first `taskId` is a local variable, the second one is a global variable. But he never uses the global `taskId`, so it's not clear why he does that.

Comment: To implement server-side events, it's better to use SSE or websockets, but if you want more universal solution, see it this side https://hpbn.co/xmlhttprequest/#streaming-data-with-xhr

Comment: Yes I agree Vladishlav, But this is just my practice project. My focus is on learning the concepts. So, I to know why exactly my expected behavior is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The Problem was not client side. I am using flask framework which by default will run in single threaded mode. So it was not serving the async requests from client side.